# Testlink 1.9.10 integration with JIRA(interface:db)

Tags: php, testlink

Has anyone integrated the Testlink 1.9.10(Ei D1 eG0) with the JIRA 5.2 using the db interface? i am using the wamp server with following config:
PHP 5.4.3
APACHE 2.2.22

i have set up an issue tracker management (connection) as given below:

```
<issuetracker>
<jiraversion>JIRA5.2</jiraversion>
<dbhost>192.168.xxx.xxx</dbhost> 
<dbname>jiradbname</dbname>
<dbtype>mssql</dbtype>
<dbuser>username</dbuser>
<dbpassword>usrpwd</dbpassword>
<uriview>http://jira.xxxx.com/browse/</uriview>
<uricreate>http://jira.xxxx.com/secure/CreateIssue.jspa</uricreate>
</issuetracker>
```

when i click on the spanner it shows some warning that "connection is KO" check configuration.

After lots of search i found that this could be due to the php mssql drivers but tried many posted resolution but no luck. can some one help me pls?

Comment: i have added the following in php.ini file:
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
and made sure these are available in the directory 
extension_dir = "c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\ext\"

Answer (score 1):

[RESOLVED]
Being a noob in the PHP it took me around 7 hrs of sourcecode debugging to find the root cause of the problem (testlink cannot connect to the MSSQL DB). which seems to be a bug to me.
as from the error >>>Message: Invalid value type for option Database was specified. String type was expected.
i was feeling from the starting that there is surely something wrong with the code/configuration of the testlink for db interface. After searching for days i finally decide to look in the source code itself and finally i have a working instance integrated with JIRA.

For Users who are facing the same problem i have a simple solution for you guys:
1. Open file issueTrackerInterface.class.php (\lib\issuetrackerintegration)
2. Goto the line 178 (in function Connect):

```
$result = $this->dbConnection->connect(false, $this->cfg->dbhost,$this->cfg->dbuser,
$this->cfg->dbpassword, $this->cfg->dbname);
```

1. comment this line.
2. paste these lines instead:

   $mydbhost = (string)($this->cfg->dbhost);
   $mydbuser = (string)($this->cfg->dbuser);
   $mydbpassword = (string)($this->cfg->dbpassword);
   $mydbname = (string)($this->cfg->dbname);

   $result = $this->dbConnection->connect(false, $mydbhost,$mydbuser,$mydbpassword, $mydbname);
3. Save your file. And its done. ; )
   please see this is how i get this worked. lets hope testlink dev guys will provide a solution to this soon.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Specify the Jira version as 5.2 instead of JIRA 5.2

It works for me.